# How to set types for a more specific function which executes a less specific function at Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

Why do I get there an error TS2322? How to handle this case to get rid of it?

In fact “makeAnimal” function is less specific and “makeCat” is more specific and as I understand, Typescript tells me that I can’t use less specific output for a more specific function.

But I need to have a common function and bunch of more specific ones which would use it.

Help me to make this right, please.

```js
const ANIMAL_CAT = 'cat'
const ANIMAL_DOG = 'dog'
type ICat = 'isCat'
type IDog = 'isDog'
type IAnimal = ICat | IDog
type IMakeAnimal = (type: string) => IAnimal
type IMakeCat = () => ICat
type IMakeDog = () => IDog

const makeAnimal: IMakeAnimal = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case ANIMAL_CAT:
            return 'isCat'
        case ANIMAL_DOG:
        default:
            return 'isDog'
    }
}

// TS2322: Type 'IAnimal' is not assignable to type '"isCat"'.
// Type '"isDog"' is not assignable to type '"isCat"'
const makeCat: IMakeCat = () => makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT)
```

Comment: You either need to *assert* that `makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT)` returns an `ICat`, or you have to rewrite `makeAnimal` to be *generic* so that the compiler can *verify* that it does.  Both techniques are shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbQPEN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: Yes it address my question, please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of your version of `makeAnimal` is just `IAnimal`, which could be either `ICat` or `IDog`.  The compiler doesn't try to simulate what happens if you call `makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT)` to narrow the return type further.  You [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) that `makeAnimal` is an `IMakeAnimal`, whose return type is `IAnimal`, so that's what the compiler sees.

---

If you want to leave the function as-is, then you'll have to add the missing information back in by *telling* the compiler that the value returned by `makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT)` is an `ICat`.  You would do that via a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const makeCat: IMakeCat = () =>
  makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT) as ICat; // okay
  // ------------------> ^^^^^^^ assert
```

That works, but it's only safe because your assertion happens to be correct.  The compiler can't tell if you make a mistake here; it relies on your assertion being accurate.  That is, the compiler isn't verifying type safety here, you are.  Case in point:

```
const makeCatBad: IMakeCat = () =>
  makeAnimal(ANIMAL_DOG) as ICat; // no errr
// --------------------> ^^^^^^^ assert
```

That also compiles with no error, but you've claimed that `makeAnimal(ANIMAL_DOG)` will return an `ICat`.  The compiler just believes you.

---

If you want more compiler-verified type safety, you need to refactor `makeAnimal()` so that its return type can depend on its input, such as making it a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function... and you also need to change the implementation so the compiler can understand that your logic matches the generic return type.  Here's one way to do it:

```
interface AnimalMap {
  [ANIMAL_CAT]: ICat,
  [ANIMAL_DOG]: IDog
}

const makeAnimal = <K extends keyof AnimalMap>(type: K): AnimalMap[K] => ({
  [ANIMAL_CAT]: 'isCat' as const,
  [ANIMAL_DOG]: 'isDog' as const
}[type]);
```

Here I've created an `AnimalMap` mapping interface that represents the relationship between the `ANIMAL_CAT`/`ANIMAL_DOG` string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) and the corresponding `ICat`/`IDog` output types.  It's just an interface, because string literal types can be used as key types for objects.

The type of `makeAnimal` is now a generic function, where the `type` parameter is of generic type `K` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof AnimalMap`, that is... `ANIMAL_CAT` or `ANIMAL_DOG`.  And the return type of `makeAnimal` is the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `AnimalMap[K]`, meaning the value type of the property of `AnimalMap` whose key type is `K`.  Essentially the call signature describes a lookup of an object property.

And indeed, I've refactored the implementation of `makeAnimal` away from a `switch`/`case` statement and to an object property lookup.  The compiler is happy with that implementation, because it sees the object as being assignable to `AnimalMap`, and the key `type` as being assignable to `K`, so the return type is seen as being assignable to `AnimalMap[K]`.  If you left it as a `switch`/`case`, you'd find that the compiler couldn't follow the logic, since `K` doesn't necessarily change just by checking `type`.

Anyway, now that `makeAnimal()` is generic, the return type will depend on the input type, and so `makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT)` will cause the compiler to infer `ANIMAL_CAT` for `K`, and the indexed access type `AnimalMap[ANIMAL_CAT]` is `ICat`, so the return type will be `ICat`.  And thus `() => makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT)` will be seen as assignable to `IMakeCat`, as desired:

```
const makeCat: IMakeCat = () => makeAnimal(ANIMAL_CAT);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggOQJIFk4BkD6BhOAVGAXhgHJgBDKEgKFElkVQ0wBEB5AcSNIBMQBzGlACeABwCmMJNkrcSASwgyq1ERKksBcxZsGqxkpHDDyAtuQA23abIA+GgfvWpyAa3HLuACgCURAHxSyk6GKG7iut5+hIFIutTUYOSm4hCi5MCSAAoATiAARhbipjAA3tQwMHTQ8MhoWLgExGSUNJXVDHXM7FzNfHqVaoaezYrKbTBDDvzaELoTU0Ym5lbENrD2cY6DBlJh7sZmlt5DAFww0DnyYPzRsYcrCe3gNeYHy5bnLu9HqzBeQzuZQqlQuAHd5FBgAALf6A4Gg0EUCCSRj1HD4U4gxGVHLiKAAVxyYFIY1a2KR5BRtSYWB6WJxMB44gAZuQCRYoAzGTA8YTiaS5gIJpUAL4g8UggD0UpgeAAygAmADMisV5zwuxIS1+JBgihgYBAsCpEHk-CShUkUBAky1ACIyVB7SQAHTS2Wa9QkR1C-gu-UQQ3GmCm82WoqTW1TH1Ol0gjowN4eShffYp2DEXwBJPhB6WLxo5iNHzUSVJFJpDKoiAonJQeTgBF25zp-N-AEGc6Xa63HM6x7Pei5n4rNN5j4d+ExZuVCAQqGwzsSPzlRnI1FdBqYimIvlEkkKJTk9dUze01icbmI5lsjlc3eg-cCo-zCnisVPKovWDJ5Tj9wRn+O4KWTdtCy3DE8D8KkgkoABuD0YAAWlQtD0IwtDAgAPVwvDsNDWtxHrL9Ez-SgACFyB4ACMyiAJQInX4IIvHoYKDdZEMqGUUMwvjMJw-DcMIusoC-MsEgrVJ0kyGAACVWQyG0cmBEFrigYi2Vk9swlEWcYAAbSLbc8AAXS+ZQABoKSMyCenM6YJQTH8R3EdtuAAHgAaRgcQAA8NLAHgg3cYQQBZeBJ10-xl3Ec4vJ8c4dPIUQDK80ycy8NdQVsi9Ggco9xkI796GsxFcvRezzlfYVio6CUDKGUzS2c4dyK5PZwiA7MZzAycWPREtENFIA)